# Getting Mac to ask for disk encryption password

Tags: hard-drive, password, encryption, filevault

Sometime in the past if I turned off the power to my Macbook Pro, when I started it up it would ask for a disk password. After that it would load the OS and ask me to select a user to login.

Now when I boot from power it no longer asks for a disk password. It goes straight to asking for a user. FileVault is still on.

How do I get it to ask for a disk password again? I don't want any user to be able to unlock it. I only want myself to be able to unlock the disk. All other users should only be able to use the machine if I've unlocked the disk first.

Answer (score 2):

The proper tool to add or remove FileVault users is *fdesetup*.

Open Terminal and enter `sudo fdesetup list -extended` to get a synopsis.

To remove a user by UUID or user name use:

```
sudo fdesetup remove -uuid <UUID>
sudo fdesetup remove -user <username>
```

All users removed won't be able to log-in with their passwords at the first password prompt because they aren't listed anymore. The user still exists as OS user though. To login as such a user either has to use fast user switching or log out as FileVault enabled user and log in with the non-FileVault-enabled user.

To reenable FileVault disabled users either use `sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd <username>` or open System Preferences > Security > FileVault > hit the "Enable Users..." button and enable a listed user.